# iOS Enable AVPlayer to continue playing in background

Tags: ios, swift, audio, video, avplayer

I'm working on an app with a built in video player that plays `mp4` videos from disk and I'm trying to make it **continue** playing the audio (of the video) when **app goes into background**.

*I've read up on many other stack overflow questions but none of the answers worked for my case.*

I have added:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
      print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")

    do {
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
      print("AVAudioSession is Active")
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
  } catch let error as NSError {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
}
```

Besides, I also have the required background mode key `App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay` in the app's Info.plist file.
However, the `AVPlayer` stops when the app goes into background.

Anyone knows what might be wrong with the app?

Thanks :)

**Edit:** Note: I'm using `AVPlayerLayer` together with `AVPlayer`. Maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `AVPlayerLayer` might be creating issue. You need to remove it from `AVPlayer` object. Set to `nil` before application go to background.

Two ways to resolve according to Apple Document,

> 1. Disable the video tracks in the player item (file-based content only).
> 2. Remove the AVPlayerLayer from its associated AVPlayer (set the
>      AVPlayerLayer player property to nil).

Refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1668/_index.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

First you must have enabled "Background Audio" in Capability. Follow bellow link to do so.

[[See image to Enable Background Audio]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btYrD.png)

When your app moves to background, assign your player to nil.

```
// If presenting video with AVPlayerViewController
    playerViewController.player = nil

// If presenting video with AVPlayerLayer
    playerLayer.player = nil
```

When your app moves to foreground again, do as given bellow.

```
// If presenting video with AVPlayerViewController
playerViewController.player = player

// If presenting video with AVPlayerLayer
playerLayer.player = player
```